# How to make an offline browser on ios?

Tags: uiwebview, asihttprequest, afnetworking, offline, offline-browsing

I need to make an offline browser on ios, which should persistent the specified webpages to the disk with the media resource such as image,css,js. At the same time, the offline browser should be able to download mutiple levels of the website automaticly, for example, make it download the webpage and all the pages linked in this webpage.

I've tried the ASIWebpageRequest,but it is not satisfying, and can not download muti levels.

Are there any other way to implement this perfectly?Can AFNetworing or MKNetworkKit do this?

Thank you very very much!